# How can you prepare data with time series and static data for classficiation?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, deep-learning, data-cleaning

I am trying to build a binary classifier to predict the propensity of customers transitioning from one account to another.
I have age, gender, cust-segment data but also a time-series of their bank balances for the last 18mths on a monthly basis and also have a lot of high cardinality categorical variables.

So, what I want to know is how do I transform the time series data so its in a more compact static form to the rest of the data points like age, gender etc. Or can I just throw this into the algorithm too?

sample data may look like the below:
customer number, age, gender, marital status code, 18mth-bal, 17mth-bal,...,3mth-bal, postcode-segment ..

Any help would be Fantastic! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would generate descriptive statistics for each time serie. Standard deviation seems interesting, but you coud also use percentiles, mean, min and max... or all of them.

```py
# add a column for the standard deviation (and/or percentiles etc.)
df['standard_deviation']= np.zeros(len(df)).astype(int)
# calculate the standard deviation with np.std() and add it to the new column
for i in df.index :
    df['standard_deviation'][i] = np.std(df.loc[[i]]['balance'][i])
```

This last line works if the content of a 'balance' cell is a list or an array (of the 18 last amounts known for this customer for example).

Sorry I can't be more specific as I can't see your dataframe, but hope it helps !